# Is it possible to open Jgrasp files across multiple displays?

Tags: java, user-interface, view, interface, jgrasp

I am using a 3 monitor set up for my computer, and none of the view options let me open and edit files across multiple monitors.  Is there an option to set something like that up?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is easy to do in jGRASP.

Open a file first, then on the bottom left of your screen, you will see this image. Click on the icon highlighted by the red circle, then that way, you can have a multi screen setup!

[image]